# upload file using jquery in pyramid

Tags: python, ajax, file-upload, pyramid

I want to upload a file using ajax: 
HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" />
<input type="button" value="Upload" id="btnUpload" />
```

avascript:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
        var file_to_upload;

    $('#photo').change(function() {
            file_to_upload = this.files[0];
        });

        $('#btnUpload').click(function () {
               var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('photo', file_to_upload);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/post_file',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {'photo' : formData},
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    enctype: "multipart/form-data",
                    success: function () {
                    }
                }, 'json');
            });
    });
```

and in py file:

```
@view_config(route_name='ajax_post_file', renderer='json')
def live_search(request):
post_data = request.POST
```

but the request.Post says:

> NoVars: Not an HTML form submission (Content-Type: text/plain)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to this in Ajax call

```
data: formData,
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test but I do see some errors. Tryt this decorator

```
@view_config(name='post_file', renderer='json')
```

Comment: I tried your idea but it is not the reason. Actually I have a router that sends the request to this function. config.add_route('ajax_post_file', '/post_file')

Comment: I see.  With my way you don't need to add the route.  Just a bit cleaner  for me.  But that doesn't answer your question; ;)